# Multilabel classification using LSTM on variable length signal using Keras

Tags: python, keras, signal-processing, lstm, multilabel-classification

I have recently started working on ECG signal classification in to various classes. It is basically multi label classification task (Total 4 classes). I am new to Deep Learning, LSTM and Keras that why i am confused in few things.

1. I am thinking about giving normalized original signal as input to the network, is this a good approach?
2. I also need to understand training input shape for LSTM as ECG signals are of variable length (9000 to 18000 samples) and usually classifier need fixed variable input. How can i handle such type of input in case of LSTM.
3. Finally what should be structure of deep LSTM network for such lengthy input and how many layers should i use.

Thanks for your time.
Regards

Answer (score 4):

> I am thinking about giving normalized original signal as input to the network, is this a good approach?

**Yes** this is a good approach. It is actually quite standard for Deep Learning algorithms to give them your input normalized or rescaled.

This usually helps your model converge faster, as now you are inside smaller range (i.e.: [-1, 1]) instead of greater un-normalized ranges from your original input (say [0, 1000]). It also helps you get better, more precise results, as it helps solve problems like the vanishing gradient as well as adapting better to modern activation and optimizer functions.

---

> I also need to understand training input shape for LSTM as ECG signals are of variable length (9000 to 18000 samples) and usually classifier need fixed variable input. How can i handle such type of input in case of LSTM.

This part is really important. You are correct, **LSTM expects to receive inputs with a fixed shape, one that you know beforehand** (in fact, any Deep Learning layer expects fixed shape inputs). This is also explained in the [keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) on Recurrent Layers where they say:

> Input shape
>
> 3D tensor with **shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)**.

As we can see, it expects your data to have a number of `timesteps` as well as a dimension on each one of those timesteps (batch size is usually 1). To exemplify, suppose your input data consists of elements like: `[[1,4],[2,3],[3,2],[4,1]]`. Then, using a `batch_size` of 1, **the shape of your data would be (1,4,2)**. As you have 4 timesteps, each with 2 features.

So bottom line, **you have to make sure that you pre-process you data so it has a fixed shape you can then pass to your LSTM layers.** This one you will have to find out by yourself, as you know your data and problem better than we do.

Maybe you can fix the samples you obtain from your signal, discarding some and keeping others so every signal is of the same length (if you say your signals are between 9k and 18k choosing 9000 could be the logical choice, discarding samples from the others you get). You could even do some other conversion to your data in a way that you can map from inputs of 9000-18000 to a fixed size.

---

> Finally what should be structure of deep LSTM network for such lengthy input and how many layers should i use.

This one is really quite broad and doesn't have a unique answer. It would depend on the nature of your problem, and determining those parameters *a priori* is not so straightforward.

What I recommend you do is to **start with a simple model first, and then add layers and blocks (neurons) incrementally until you are satisfied with the results.**

Try just one hidden layer first, train and test your model and check your performance. You can then add more blocks and see if your performance improved. You can also add more layers and check for the same until you are satisfied.

This is a good way to create Deep Learning models, as you will arrive to the results you want while keeping your Network as lean as possible, which in turn helps your execution time and complexity. Good luck with your coding, hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks @DarkCygnus for details explanation much appreciated! Where i am still confused is the timesteps. Timesteps here are number of samples?

Comment: Secondly is it fine to give actual normalized signal or should i extract features from the signal and give these features as input... considering my input size what would be the best?

Comment: @Naqvi by timesteps it means the "temporal" dimension your ECG has. In other words in the example given it was `4` because a single element of your dataset consists of four discrete samples of that continuous signal (which coincidentally had 2 features each), and each one with different voltages (or whatever unit) on each point. Like 4 "frames" or pictures on specific moments of the signal.

Comment: So in your example we have two input samples with four features each right?

Comment: @Naqvi `[[1,4],[2,3],[3,2],[4,1]]`that was a *single* input sample with 4 *timesteps* and 2 *features per sample*. Which was basically two signals with 4 samples (timestamp) each.

Comment: @Naqvi and yes, now you have to actually *define a fixed timestamp* for your data. You can well sample down to 9000 everything, or a smarter move could be to extract features and train with those. You will also be helping your efficiency and compactness of your models by doing that. In that case if you chose to extract `N` features your shape will be (1,N,1), as you only have one feature per timestep in an ECG I suppose. You could try training with *batches* (something like (5,N,1) on its shape) but that is a different matter.

Comment: actually i am trying to replicate deep net using LSTM that was previously training using Resnet... In which they took max size (18000) and masked short values with zeros that were less than 18000. I am still confused will that approach work in LSTM but i should try first. In this case i guess my input will become LSTM(128, 18000,1)  for 128 being batch size and each timestep containing 18000 samples right?

Comment: @Naqvi Sounds like something that could work, you should try it out. Also as alternative I think why not exclude those elements that are not of 18k samples each, and train with only those? Or maybe some of the signals that are longer have much noise or baseline on it which you could remove I guess... And yes, if you fixed the timestep to 18k samples and trained with batches of 128 then it would be (128,18000,1) given you have a single feature.

Comment: Thanks man things are pretty much clear now.. i am going to give it a go...